# How to get JavaScriptSerializer to treat a sub-object as a plain old string?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have JSON coming into my program like this:

```
{
    "Foo": "some string",
    "Bar": { "Quux" : 23 }
}
```

How can I use `JavaScriptSerializer` to parse this, **but treat the Bar value as a string** instead of a sub-object? The code below throws an exception, as expected.

After deserialization, I want `thing.Bar` to contain the *string* `{ "Quux" : 23 }`.
Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

```
class Thing
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{ \"Foo\": \"some string\", \"Bar\": { \"Quux\": 23 }}";
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var thing = serializer.Deserialize<Thing>(json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement your own JavaScriptConverter to do this... here is an example...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Thing
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "{\"Foo\":\"some string\",\"Bar\":{\"Quux\":23}}";
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] {
                new StringConverter()           
            });
            var thing = serializer.Deserialize<Thing>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(thing.Bar);
        }
    }

    public class StringConverter : JavaScriptConverter
    {
        public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
        {
            get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(new List<Type>(new Type[] { typeof(string) })); }
        }

        public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            var i = dictionary.First();
            return "{ \"" + i.Key + "\" : " + i.Value + " }";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it's very helpful. It works great for the sample I gave. Unfortunately, Quux can be more complicated than just a number like 23, it can be any JSON object, with sub-objects and sub-sub-objects of its own.

Comment: Late, quick question... I see this in every JavaScriptConverter implementation: `return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(new List<Type>(new Type[] { typeof(...) }));` -- why did you choose to implement the SupportedTypes property like this? Why not simply `return new [] { typeof(string) };`?

Comment: Don't quite remember, but I think it was just me being lazy and cutting and pasting code from somewhere else :).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the contents of Bar in quotes?

```
{
    "Foo": "some string",
    "Bar": "{ 'Quux' : 23 }"
}
```